# How to find speed bottleneck in NSArrayController?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

In my app I have a list of categories with a property that is an array of objects. An NSTreeController's content property is bound to that array of the current category. The categories are in a list from which the user can select one. The selected category is stored in a property of the window controller to which the array controller is bound. This works all nicely.

However, when the users switches the category the array controller gets a new content array and this process is comparably slow. With around 12000 objects in the array it takes like 3 secs. The loading time directly depends on the amount of objects. The less in the array the faster this process. As a side node the objects in the array are loaded from CoreData.

Obviously, the array controller is doing something with each of the objects. Breaking execution during that time always ends up in some objc_msgSend() call. I need to find out what it is doing actually, so I can fix that. I just don't know how.

I tried the Time Profiler to see what's going on, but drilling down the call stack is not helping much. You get into a deep nesting of messages each taking a bit of time and at the end there's no single point where you can say this is it.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning on sql debug on Core Data so that you can see what the SQL statements look like.  The only performance improvements that you can do are in the predicate themselves.  Strings are expensive, numbers are cheap, just like queries in a database.

Searching 12000 objects on OS X should not be that slow. I suspect there are performance improvements to be had in your predicate.

Comment: I don't think the bottleneck is CoreData, because at the time of switching the categories all data is already loaded. It's just a matter for replacing the content of an array controller with another array and propagating that to the application.